# cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize function equivalent in pycuda

Tags: cuda, pycuda

I want to compute the optimal gridsize and blocksize in order to have a high rate of occupancy for a kernel launch. I have seen that there is a function in CUDA to do so, which is this one:

```
cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize()
```

I am using PyCUDA and I would like to know if an equivalent function exists in PyCUDA.

Comment: Highest occupancy not always can be achieved with the maximum block size - that is, smaller blocks may be able to achieve higher occupancy.

Answer (score 1):

As best as I can tell, the driver API occupancy functions, including `cuOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize`, have not been implemented in PyCUDA, as of version 2015.1.3, [based on a search of the Github mirror](https://github.com/inducer/pycuda/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=cuOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize+).